# How can I generate a url to a new AppInsights query?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a process that generates AppInsights telemetry. I would like to prove a link to a query in AppInsights. However, it is not the same query every time - the parameters change. I know I can share a link to an existing query, but how do I generate such a link to a new query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your **Application Insights Query Editor**, we have an option called **Copy link to query**. In this link we have following details:
[image]
The URL generated from this action has the following format:

> https://portal.azure.com/#@ **TENANT_ID**/blade/Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring_Logs/LogsBlade/resourceId/%2Fsubscriptions%2F **SUBSCRIPTION_ID** %2FresourceGroups%2F< **RESOURCEGROUP**%2Fproviders%2Fmicrosoft.insights%2Fcomponents%2F **APPLICATION INSIGHTS_INSTANCE_NAME** /source/LogsBlade.AnalyticsShareLinkToQuery/q/ **ENCODED
> BASE 64_KQL_QUERY** /timespan/TIMESPAN

I’ve emphasized in bold here the parameters of the URL. These parameters have the following values:

**TENANT_ID:** Your Tenant ID

**SUBSCRIPTION_ID**: Your Azure Subscription ID that contains the Application Insights instance.

**RESOURCE_GROUP:** Your Resource Group where the Application Insights instance is deployed.

**APPINSIGHTS_INSTANCE_NAME:** Your Application Insights instance Name.

**ENCODED_KQL_QUERY:**  Base64 encoding of your query text zipped and URL encoded

**TIMESPAN:** time filter for the query (optional).

If your query has less than `1600` characters, you can also replace the ***q*** parameter in the above URL with a ***query*** parameter, and the encoded string will simply be your query plain text escaped (without zipping and encoding).

**Dynamic URL it’s important to:**

- Take the text of your KQL query
- Zip it
- Encode it in Base64

A C# code that does the encoding of the **KQL query** is the following:

Generate the Query whatever you want and pass that into the below function to get the Encoded base 64 URL and you can add this in a base URL of application insights.

```
    static string Encodedbase64KQLQuery(string query)
    {
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(query);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (GZipStream compressedStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, leaveOpen: true))
            {
                compressedStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        Byte[] bytedata = memoryStream.ToArray();
        string encodedBase64Query = Convert.ToBase64String(bytedata);
        return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encodedBase64Query);
        }
    }
```

Please visit this [blog](https://demiliani.com/2022/01/11/create-a-link-to-an-application-insights-query-programmatically/) which helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Delliganesh and Stefano from the blog link. Here is a simple JavaScript example. Be sure to replace all 4 constant values at top and the sessionId when calling the function. You can also tweak the query, but just keep in mind the 1600 character limit as described above and in the blog.

```
const APP_INSIGHTS_INSTANCE_NAME = "APP_INSIGHTS_INSTANCE_NAME";
const APP_INSIGHTS_RESOURCE_GROUP = "APP_INSIGHTS_RESOURCE_GROUP";
const APP_INSIGHTS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "APP_INSIGHTS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID";
const APP_INSIGHTS_TENANT_ID = "APP_INSIGHTS_TENANT_ID";

const getAppInsightsQueryUrl = ({ sessionId }) => {
  const query = `requests | where session_Id == "${sessionId}"`;
  const url = `https://portal.azure.com/#@${APP_INSIGHTS_TENANT_ID}/blade/Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring_Logs/LogsBlade/resourceId/%2Fsubscriptions%2F${APP_INSIGHTS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}%2FresourceGroups%2F${APP_INSIGHTS_RESOURCE_GROUP}%2Fproviders%2Fmicrosoft.insights%2Fcomponents%2F${APP_INSIGHTS_INSTANCE_NAME}/source/LogsBlade.AnalyticsShareLinkToQuery/query/${encodeURI(
    query
  )}/timespan/TIMESPAN`;
  return url;
};


getAppInsightsQueryUrl({
  sessionId: 'my-session-id',
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).